# Can one move egg shells on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, muktzeh, eggs

Let's say someone makes egg salad on Shabbos and when peeling the eggs puts the peels in a cup. Is this cup allowed to be moved (even without adding anything that's permitted to be moved in the cup)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shells are fit for consumption by a kind of animal that is common in the area you're in [or, I assume, that you own a specimen of], then they are not *muktzim*. (*Sh'mira Shabas K'hilchasah* 20:27.)

If, however, they're not, then they are *muktzim*. One should release the shells from his hand as soon as feasible after peeling the eggs (*SSK* 20:26), though one need not do so *immediately* (*SSK* 22:33).

*SSK* 22:fn38 struggles to explain why the plate or cup the shells are placed in does not become *muktze*, but nonetheless accepts that as fact. Thus, one can carry the plate to the trash receptacle and tip the shells out; likewise, if the shells are on the table, one can wipe them off — but without touching them. This assumes you're doing so because you need the table/plate clean or because the shells' sitting there disgusts you; otherwise, it may be forbidden to move the shells by any means. (*SSK* 22:36.)

(Citations to *SSK* are to the 5739 edition.)

Comment: This is from ages ago, but in my understanding, the plate or cup doesn't become a "basis" unless you placed the muktzeh on top of it in Bein HaShemashot.